# Unexpected data found. Trailing data laravel and carbon

Tags: laravel

I want 'add days' to be created in database, but got this error in laravel,

**Unexpected data found. Trailing data**

[image]

format column created_at is datetime

```
    $packages = Package::find($id);
   
    $licenceF = Licence::where('tbl_package_id' , $id)
        ->select('created_at')
        ->get();

    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $licenceF);

    $findPackage = Package::where('id' , $request->input('tbl_package_id'))->pluck('time');
    $licenceF = $licenceF->addDays($findPackage);
```

Comment: You're passing `$licenseF` to `Carbon::createFromFormat` instead of an actual field with string date. You should do `Carbon::createFromFormat('...', $licenceF->created_at)`

Comment: get this error Property [created_at] does not exist on this collection instance.
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $licenceF->created_at);

Comment: My bad, `->get()` returns collection, replace it with `->first()` or use `$licenceF[0]->created_at` to get `created_at` of first element in collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Carbon::parse()` instead of `Carbon::createFromFormat()` as follows :

`$licenceF = Carbon::parse($findPackage[0]->created_at)->addDays($findPackage);`

You can get the query result as an array as well using :

`$licenceF = License::where('tbl_package_id' , $id)->select('created_at')->get()->toArray()`

and later using

`$licenceF[0]['created_at']`

The difference between `parse` and `createFromFormat` is that the second method tries to "guess" the format of the date string you pass as an argument. This might be handy if you have your own class for date manipulation.

I hope I was helpful

Comment: I have a question , Each license has a separate created_at, how can change each licence date ?

Answer (score 0):

I write this code for change each license created_at, but date of first row in database update for all column

```
foreach ($licenceF as $items){
        $items = Carbon::parse($items->created_at)->addDays($findPackage->time);
        $items->format('Y-m-d');

        if($items){
            $newdate = Licence::where('tbl_package_id', '=', $id)->update([
                'tbl_package_id' => $request->input('tbl_package_id'),
                'expires_at' => $items,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this portion of code, the error lies in writing the foreach loop. You are using an iterator variable called $items to iterate through your set of licenses. In the next statement use the same variable name to compute the new date to update. Use a different variable name that hints at what it contains. Something like $newLicDate = Carbon::parse($items->created_at)->addDays($findPackage->time)->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: The second error is in the update query. In the where clause you identify your record via the tbl_package_id attribute I don't understand why that value needs to be updated? It will most likely be a primary key that I don't recommend you update.